# Unity problem in Ubuntu 16.04 after update

Tags: 16.04, unity

After recent update my unity looks strange: background is black and I can't change it (but in my conky i can see part of it), i can't see highlighted text, everything is with white background (even context menu), even greeting screen, where you type in password is looking odd - you can see it in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23A99.png).
What can be done about it?

Comment: Have you themed your system?

Comment: @heynnema, nope, just changed wallpapers and installed conky at some point, but it was long ago

Comment: Log into another account on the system and see if it looks ok there. Create a temporary guest account if need be.

Comment: @heynnema, the same on guest account

Comment: What updates occurred before the problem started? Are you able to reset your desktop background?

Comment: I can't say exactly, just as usual ubuntu proposed to update things. I didn't checked them. Is it possible to check it now?

Comment: Are you able to reset your desktop background picture? `cat /var/log/dpkg.log` or `cat /var/log/dpkg.log.1` should show you what got installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94383/discussion-between-alexander-zh-and-heynnema).